# Can anyone explain me the working of this python code?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Can anyone explain the working of this code? I thought this code will give an error but it is running perfectly.

```
arrayEle = numpy.prod

a=[1,2,3]
print(arrayEle(a))
```

I expect the compile error but it is running fine.

Comment: numpy.prod takes an array...https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/numpy-prod-python/

Comment: Which part did you expect to give you an error? That might help give a more relevant explanation.

Comment: `arrayELE` is a typo of `arrayEle` I guess?

Comment: that was the typo error, my mistake, I fixed that.

Comment: @ Sayuj Sehgal ...It was a good question about Python..+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should run perfectly. You are assigning the function `numpy.prod` to `arrayEle` by `arrayEle = numpy.prod`.

Now calling `arrayEle(a)` is as same as calling `numpy.prod(a)`